# Using a Microsoft Windows Certificate Store in node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am trying to create a node https server.  The idea is that the server will receive the thumbprint of a certificate in the store, pull it out of the store and use it for SSL/TLS connection.  I have done examples for self-signed certificates and it has worked fine.
I have the code to look through the certificate store and find the correct certificate based on its thumbprint

The code I have so far is below.

```
const ca = require('win-ca');
const forge = require('node-forge');
const pki = forge.pki;
const ssh = forge.ssh;

const thumbprint = process.env.THUMBPRINT; 
...

for (let cert of ca.all()) {
        console.log(forge.pki.certificateToPem(cert));
        console.log('  -----------  \r');
        const md = forge.md.sha1.create();

md.update(forge.asn1.toDer(forge.pki.certificateToAsn1(cert)).getBytes());
            const hex = md.digest().toHex();
            console.log(hex);
        console.log('\r');
        if (thumbprint === hex) {
            foundCert = cert;
            console.log('found\r');
            break;
        }


    }
    console.log('**********************');
    console.log('\r');

    //}
    cnt++;
}

if (foundCert) {
    console.log(forge.pki.certificateToPem(foundCert));

    const pm = forge.pki.certificateToPem(foundCert);
    console.log(foundCert);
}
```

In windows ASP.NET Core, one only needs the the certificate for https.  For node.js, all the examples use a private key. I don't have the private key, but I have access to the machine's certificate store.  Can I use the certificate from the store without the private key?  There seems to be a piece I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: (just found bookmark, sorry) Any SSL-now-TLS server needs the cert _and_ privatekey. dot-NET _does_ have it, 'hidden' [inside X509Certificate2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_PrivateKey). I haven't seen any way for nodejs to get this directly, but https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge apparently lets you call dot-NET which might (no-export setting in CSP should affect it, but I don't see that mentioned)